# native reverse links in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

For example I created post with two comments:

```
db.posts.save(id: 'xxx');
db.comments.save(id:'c1', post: 'xxx', text: 'first comment');
db.comments.save(id:'c2', post: 'xxx', text: 'second comment');
```

I want to get data about comments in posts.find():

```
[{id: 'xxx', commentsCount: 2}]
```

or better:

```
[{id: 'xxx', comments:['c1', 'c2']}]
```

I want to do it with native mongodb methods (without manual updating of collection 'posts'). Read about DbRefs and MapReduce, but didnt understand how to solve my task.

Comment: How did you define your schema?

Comment: I dont know how to define schema in mongodb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to retrieve documents in a transformed manner, you are looking for the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/).

First you use the [$match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operator to narrow the aggregation down to the relevant documents. In this case you want to create one document based on many, so you need the [$group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operator.

This would give you a document with an array for a specific post:

```
db.comments.aggregate([
    { $match: {
            post:'xxx'
        }
    },
    { $group: {
            id: "$post",
            comments: { $push: "$text" }
        }
    },
]);
```

This would give you a document with a count:

```
db.comments.aggregate([
    { $match: {
            post:'xxx'
        }
    },
    { $group: {
            id: "$post",
            commentsCount: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
]);
```

Comment: There is one post in my example, but really there are many posts. Should I execute aggregate query for each post?

Comment: @ИванПетров That depends on what you actually want to do.

Comment: I want to get all posts with comments count by one query. Can you show me how to do this?

Comment: @ИванПетров Easy: Just omit the `$match` step in the aggregation pipeline and you will group all documents by their post fields.

Comment: Works! Can I combine aggregate with usual find query?

Comment: @ИванПетров A $match step in your aggregation pipeline can do everything you can do with find.